# How to find how many rectangular prisms ( including cubes) are in a n by n by n cube?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

I somehow got the answer to be [(n+1)!/2!(n+1-2)!]^2 *n

Each part of the equation represents the height, length, and width of the possible rectangular prism in the big cube. You can multiply the total choices to get the final answer. Don't know if this is right though.

Comment: You could write your formula much more clearly, even without using $\LaTeX$.  It is not clear where the parentheses go.  It would also be better to show the logic you used to derive it, so we could comment on it.

Comment: What is LATEX?.

Comment: $\LaTeX$ is how people get nice looking math here.  A tutorial is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you require the prism to be aligned with the axes, you have to choose two coordinates in each axis from $[0,n]$, so it is ${n+1 \choose 2}^3$

Comment: Why is it cubed but not squared? Could u explain your logic? Please

Comment: You choose two values for the limits in $x$, then again for $y$, then again for $z$. All the axes are treated the same, so you would expect a cubic function.

Comment: Thanks, Ross. Do you any idea as to how many pyramids are in a pyramid?

Comment: The same basic idea.  If you have a square pyramid, any square that you select determines the peak.  If the base is $n \times n$, you add up the number of squares in $1 \times 1$, $2 \times 2$, etc.

Comment: What about those small pyramids in the center?

Comment: Those come from (say) the $1 \times 1$ squares on the base, or the squares on a mid-level tier.  I am assuming all the pyramids have to be oriented with the base parallel to the $xy$ plane.  It is not as clear what pyramids you want to count.

Comment: I will posting this as my new problem. Thanks for spending time on my irrelevant questions

Comment: Waitt, Ross, your formula seems to be incorrect. Use n=2 for example. It would yield 27. But in reality, there is only 21.

Comment: You have three choices for the range in each axis, making $27$.  You can have $[0,1],[0,2],[1,2]$.  Why aren't there $27$?

Comment: In a 2 by 2 cube, there are 8 single unit cubes, and 8 ,1 by 1 by 2 , rectangular prisms, and 4, 1by 2 by2, rectangular prisms. In total there are 20. Plus the large cube itself, it's 21.

Comment: There are six $1 \times 2 \times 2$ blocks-you can cut the cube in half with three planes, each yielding two blocks.  There are twelve $1 \times 1 \times 2$-four parallel to each axis.